# What's wrong with this mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT app_contracts.*, app_customers.id as customer, app_boards.id as board
 WHERE app_customers.id=app_contracts.customer_id 
 AND app_boards.id=app_contracts.board_id 
 ORDER BY app_contracts.id DESC
```

Error:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'WHERE
>   app_customers.id=app_contracts.customer_id
>   AND app_boards.id=app_contracts' at
>   line 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to select FROM something (a table, say) before your WHERE-clause

Answer (score 8):

You're missing the "FROM" clause before the "WHERE".

SELECT app_contracts.*, app_customers.id as customer, app_boards.id as board
**FROM app_customers, app_contracts**
WHERE app_customers.id=app_contracts.customer_id
AND app_boards.id=app_contracts.board_id
ORDER BY app_contracts.id DESC

Answer (score 3):

There is no FROM clause

Answer (score 1):

This one must work:

```
 SELECT app_contracts.*, app_customers.id as customer, app_boards.id as board
 FROM app_customers, app_contracts, app_boards
 WHERE app_customers.id=app_contracts.customer_id 
 AND app_boards.id=app_contracts.board_id 
 ORDER BY app_contracts.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified a table(s) from which to select the data.  It should be more of the form:

```
SELECT app_contracts.*, app_customers.id as customer, app_boards.id as board
FROM app_contracts, app_customers, app_boards
JOIN ...
WHERE app_customers.id=app_contracts.customer_id 
AND app_boards.id=app_contracts.board_id 
ORDER BY app_contracts.id DESC
```

Where `JOIN ...` specifies the keys by which the three tables should be related.